# Mount remote project Windows 7 - alternatives to samba

Tags: windows, git, netbeans, samba

We work on remote server. Project is on remote server, we get this project to local machine, but all scripts are execute on server.

In the past I work on Linux and mount project by sshfs - all works great but now I have to work on Windows 7 - mount project by samba, and all is SLOW.

Any alternatives to get remote project?

I use Netbeans, Windows 7 + GIT.

PS. I know this program to SSHFS on Windows but this is not stable - many blue screen.

Comment: Have you considered sharing your projects source code by using a Version Control System like Git or Mercurial?

Comment: It's not quite clear why you need to work on a file share when your source code is in Git - simply create a local repository and your performance issue is solved.